# processing the data on peripheral side

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using qt to create a ble (Bluetooth low energy) server (peripheral), I am following this link http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-heartrate-server-example.html.
I am able to advertise and also braodcast the data which I gave in one of the characterstics, 
I have written another characteristic in which I need to get and process the data on my peripheral side when central device writes data into that characteristic. I am using nrf app as a central device.

My concern is that how should I know that data is written to central device, I mean how can I notify myself on peripheral side that somedata is passed from the central device, and also how to collect that data on peripheral side.